# Microsoft PHP SQL Driver 1.1

Tags: php, sql-server

Will microsofts SQL for PHP driver version 1.1 work with x64 builds of php 5.3?
It's not a general question as much as it sounds, we are currently having trouble with it. I just would like to know if someone can confirm if it works/should work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it will not work on x64 builds of php. Though the x86 builds of php work fine on x64 operative systems and so will the sql driver. It is tested and confirmed for version 1.1 of the driver.